# Replace complete line getting number from variable

Tags: sed

I have a file with a certain line, let's say...

```
AAA BBB CCC
```

I need to replace that entire line, after finding it, so I did:

```
q1=`grep -Hnm 1 "AAA" FILE | cut -d : -f 2`
```

That outputs me the line number of the first occurrence (in q1), because it has more than one occurrence, now, here comes my problem... In a previous step I was using this sed to replace a certain line in the file:

```
sed -e '3s/.*/WHATEVER/' FILE
```

To replace (in the example, line 3) the full line with WHATEVER, but now if I try to use $q1 instead of the "3" indicating the line number it doesn't work:

```
sed -e '$q1s/.*/WHATEVER/' FILE
```

It's probably a stupid syntax mistake, any help is welcome; thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using `grep` `cut` and `sed`, why not just use `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`sed -e "${q1}s/.*/WHATEVER/" FILE`

Comment: Better use double quotes instead of single quotes, so the shell variable can be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk for this:

```
awk '/AAA/ && !r {print "WHATEVER"; r=1; next} {print}' <<END
a
b
AAA BBB CCC
d
e
AAA foo bar
f
END
```

```
a
b
WHATEVER
d
e
AAA foo bar
f
```

Comment: What's the benefit of awk over sed?

Comment: You can use variables in awk, not sed. So you can know if it's the *first* time you've seen that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the first occurrence of a string in a file, you could use this awk script:

```
awk '/occurrence/ && !f++ {print "replacement"; next}1' file
```

The replacement will only be printed the first time, as `!f++` will only evaluate to true once (on subsequent evaluations, `f` will be greater than zero so `!f` will be false. The `1` at the end is always true, so for each line other than the matched one, awk does the default action and prints the line.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
blah
blah
occurrence 1 and some other stuff
blah
blah
some more stuff and occurrence 2
blah
$ awk '/occurrence/ && !f++ {print "replacement"; next}1' file
blah
blah
replacement
blah
blah
some more stuff and occurrence 2
blah
```

The "replacement" string could easily be set to the value of a shell variable in the following way:

```
awk -v rep="$r" '/occurrence/ && !f++ {print rep; next}1' file
```

where `$r` is a shell variable.

Using the same file as above and the example variable in your comment:

```
$ q2="x=\"Second\""
$ awk -v rep="$q2" '/occurrence/ && !f++ {print rep; next}1' file
blah
blah
x="Second"
stuff
blah
blah
some more stuff and occurrence 2
blah
```

Comment: Got a problem with this one... in this case, my "replacement" is a variable q2="x=\"Second\"", but when replacing it only writes "Second" instead of the full string stored at q2.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me, see the update to my answer.

Comment: Perfect now with that update! And yeah guys, seems that awk saves a lot of lines, but i'm still not an expert with it ;). Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "${q1} c\
WHATEVER" YourFile
```

but you can directly use

```
sed '/YourPatternToFound/ {s/.*/WHATEVER/
:a
N;$!ba
}' YourFile
```