# Bash: using sed with a variable line number, and variables in the line replacement

Tags: bash, sed

So I have seen this question: [Replace complete line getting number from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023170/replace-complete-line-getting-number-from-variable)
which is pretty similar, but in my case I am trying to use multiple variables: one for the line number [lineNo], one for the text to replace [transFormatted] and the file to which it should be looking in [OUTPUT_FILE] I've tried dozens of combinations to try to get it to recognize all these variables but nothing seems to work. It's unhappy no matter which way I try. What am I doing wrong?

```
sed -e '${lineNo}s/.*/${transFormatted}/' < $OUTPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit parameter expansion.

```
sed -e "${lineNo}s/.*/$transFormatted/" < "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to 's' "

Comment: Then you have other problems.

Comment: I think it's still related to variable expansion though. because it's saying that the s option is bad which would be the variable expansion to lineNo. I echoed it right before and know it's spitting out a valid integer.

Comment: Did you see what else it's spitting out? Try putting it through `od`.

Comment: It might be due to "!" (or some special character) present in any of your values, rest, answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use double quotes for the variables to be expanded from the shell environment.