# Insert variable in specific place using sed -i

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i would insert two variable in sed command:

```
sed -i '39,41 s/^#//' file
```

i would

```
sed -i '$LINE,$LINE_INCREMENTED s/^#//' file
```

but return this:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `$'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in a command in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed), or [shell variables in sed script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7006910/3266847), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319607/bash-using-sed-with-a-variable-line-number-and-variables-in-the-line-replaceme), and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177167/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell variables are not expanded when put inside single quotes, they are treated literally then.

Do:

```
sed -i "$LINE,$LINE_INCREMENTED"' s/^#//' file
```

Assuming the variables only contain digits.

As `s/^#//` part does not contain any shell expansion, putting double quotes over the full expression would do too, better readability:

```
sed -i "$LINE,$LINE_INCREMENTED s/^#//" file
```

Comment: with this syntax doesn't work i've this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `4'

Answer (score 0):

drop the quotes for double quotes so environment variables are evaluated:

```
sed -i "$LINE,$LINE_INCREMENTED s/^#//" file
```